# Peewee dynamically generate where clause to check for duplicates

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I am currently using peewee as an ORM in a python project. 
I am trying to determine given a set of objects if any of these objects already exist in the database. For objects where the uniqueness is based on one key that is simple -- I can generate a list of the keys and do a select in the database:

`Model.select().where(Model.column << ids)`

However, in some cases the uniqueness is determined by two columns. (Note that I don't have the primary key in hand at this moment, which is why I can't just rely on `id`.)

I tried to genericize the logic, where a list of all the column names that determined uniqueness could be passed in. Here is my code:

```
    clauses = []
    for obj in db_objects:
        # get_unique_key returns a tuple of the all the column values
        # that determine uniqueness for this object.
        uniq_key = self._get_unique_key(obj)
        subclause = [getattr(self.model_class, uniq_column) == value
                     for uniq_column, value in zip(self.uniq_columns, uniq_key)]

        clauses.append(reduce(operator.and_, subclause))

    dups = self.model_class.select().where(reduce(operator.or_, clauses)).execute()
```

Note that `self.dup_columns` contains the names of all the columns that together determine uniqueness, and `_get_unique_key` returns a tuple of those column values.

When I run this I get an error that max recursion depth has been exceeded. I suppose this is due to how peewee resolves expressions. One way around it might be to break up my clauses into some max amount of objects (i.e. create a clause for every 100 objects and then issue the query, and do this until all the objects have been processed).

Wanted to see if there was a better way instead.

Comment: Can you please share the full traceback?